# WiFi.setOutputPower();

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I'm trying to cut my esp8266 range down to about a meter to save power.  I know that I can adjust output power but I don't know enough to understand what a given setting will actually yield.

I can set zero to kill it or 20.5 to set max range, but what setting is appropriate for a meter or so?  Is there a rule of thumb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual WiFi range is highly dependent on many more factors than just the TX power:

1. The antenna gain, directionality, and orientation of the receiver
2. The antenna gain, directionality, and orientation of the transmitter
3. The proximity of radio-reflective objects nearby (metal)
4. The proximity of radio absorbing objects nearby (humans)
5. RF Black Magic

In practice, test your situation by running a series of tests at lower and lower power settings until you get an unreliable connection, then bump it up a couple of notches from there.

Do not rely on transmitter power for security, however. You cannot stop someone from pointing a high-gain antenna at your device and communicating with it from a distance farther than 1 meter. TX power reduction should primarily be for energy conservation.

Comment: Thank you.  Am I correct in assuming that .01 would be extremely short range and 20.5 would be max range?

Comment: The lowest power output is `0`;